# How to restart audio in React Component using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying make a soundboard using React. I've pulled some code from other stack overflow answers but what I can't get to work is to have the audio restart when triggered again during playback. Instead it just continues to play to the end.

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = (props) => {

    const useAudio = url => {
        const [audio] = useState(new Audio(url));
        const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

        const toggleSound = () => setPlaying(!playing);

        useEffect(() => {
                playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
            },
            [playing]
        );

        useEffect(() => {
            audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
            return () => {
                audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
            };
        }, []);

        return [playing, toggleSound];
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleClick(e) {
            if(e.key === props.trigger){
                toggleSound();
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleClick);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleClick);
        };
    }, []);

    const [playing, toggleSound] = useAudio(`./sounds/${props.audio}`);

    return (
        <ButtonWrapper playing={playing} onClick={toggleSound}>
            {props.children} - {props.trigger.toUpperCase()}
        </ButtonWrapper>
    )
}

export default Button;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.button`
    background: ${props => props.playing ? 'red' : 'white'};
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use .load() method?

The reference says that .load() reloads the element https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp